# How can I keep all the key columns and do the Pandas dataframe join?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join

I need to join 2 dataframes using the same key I created several temporary dataframe while doing the join The code below works fine, but I wonder if there is a way to keep both of the join key columns like subj_x and subj_y when joining the two pandas dataframes below with subj as key. Thanks

```
head = [['nationality', 'BART', 'USA']]
body = [['placeOfBirth', 'BART', 'NEWYORK'], ['hasFather', 'BART', 'HOMMER']]
head_df = pd.DataFrame(head, columns = ['pred', 'subj', 'obj'])
body_df = pd.DataFrame(body, columns = ['pred', 'subj', 'obj'])
joined_df = pd.merge(head_df, body1_df, on='subj')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting column `subj_x` and `subj_y` because you are joining the dfs `on=subj` from both columns and since you have not provided `how` parameter in `merge` hence pandas is redirecting it to default merge which is `inner`.

You can merge dfs on various parameters, details [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

We can do outer join if we want complete data set from both dataframes.

```
joined_df = pd.merge(head_df, body_df, how='outer')
```

**Output**

```
    pred            subj    obj
0   nationality     BART    USA
1   placeOfBirth    BART    NEWYORK
2   hasFather       BART    HOMMER
```

If we want to join on column axis to get all the data from both dataframes.

```
joined_df = pd.concat([head_df, body_df], join='outer', axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
    pred        subj    obj pred          subj  obj
0   nationality BART    USA placeOfBirth  BART  NEWYORK
1   NaN         NaN     NaN hasFather     BART  HOMMER
```